# No API definition provided. - openApi - springdoc

Tags: openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui, springdoc-openui

I have a simple boot application where I have added open api swagger dependency

```
springdoc-openapi-ui
```

along with these properties

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html
```

I am getting these error (when calling http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html):

```
No API definition provided.
```

this is my controller :

```
@RestController
public class HelloWorld {

@GetMapping("sayHi")
public String sayHi(){
    return "Hi Beno";
}
}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

When using a different endpoint to serve the OpenAPI Config, you'll need to set two properties

```
// This will set UI to fetch the config's URL from "somePath"
springdoc.swagger-ui.configUrl=somePath

// You also need to serve the config file from the endpoint at "somePath"
springdoc.api-docs.path=somePath
```